# How model circular dependency in dagger2?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, dagger-2

How can I model circular dependency using dagger2?
Lets say we have only two classes. First injection is via constructor and second is via method as in example below:

```
class A{
    private B b;

    @Inject
    public A(B b)
    {
        this.b = b;
    }
}

class B{
    private A a;

    @Inject
    public B() { }

    @Inject
    public void injectA(A a)
    {
        this.a = a;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [lazy](https://dagger.dev/api/latest/dagger/Lazy.html) injection:

```
class B{
    private Lazy<A> a;

    @Inject
    public B(Lazy<A> a) {
       this.a = a;
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can inject `Provider<A>`, but be aware that provider returns new instance of A each time `Provider::get` is invoked (assuming default scope), while `Lazy::get` returns the same instance.

Answer (score 1):

Inject a `Provider<A>` or `Provider<B>` into one of them instead of an A or B directly.  Then as long as the two classes don't both need the other in the constructor it will work.  If they both need each other in their constructors, then there's no way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge you can’t.

Dependencies like this indicate that A  and B might be tighter than they should be. Either merge them or refactor out the common part in C

Comment: You can inject a Provider<A> which allows for lazy initialization of A.  Then if A isn't needed during the constructor of B, it will work.

Comment: @GabeSechan I can read and that is not what was asked for. Why does A and B need each other?

Comment: Its exactly what it asks for.  Being able to inject a circular dependence.  As for why A and B need each other-  Who knows?  Not enough info.  Its sometimes a smell, but there's also situations where its necessary.

Comment: @GabeSechan Well the B given to the A given to the B Will not be the same B. This is bad advice.

Comment: It depends on how you're constructing the A and B.  Frequently this is done for singletons, in which case it absolutely will be.  There's a lot of flexibility in dagger to make this work right.  Including if necessary assisted injection.  Further insight itno the right additional changes to make would require more info on his usecase.